# SSRS chart issue

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Just try to generate a chart using some values. It is working fine but along with chart values one extra column displayed in the chart. How to restrict that? Please find the below image. In that I dont want to show 13. Just I want to generate a chart upto 12 only. Hope you understand

[image: testreport]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you already solved this problem.  On the off chance you haven't solved the problem, have you tried setting a maximum bound value to 12?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a chart filter. That should ignore the extra rows